# Typed key-value-pair object in Typescript with saving keyof the object

Tags: typescript

I have the key-value-pair object in the following example

```
interface ItemType {
    a: number;
    b: string;
}

const list = {
    first: {a: 1, b: 'one'},
    second: {a: 2, b: 'two'},
    third: {a: 3, b: 'three'},
} as { [key in keyof typeof list]: ItemType }
```

But it raises an error such as `TS2313: Type parameter 'key' has a circular constraint.`.

I want all items to be of type of `ItemType`, but still want the list to save keys that I have inserted. If I cast it to `{ [key in string]: ItemType }`, I will loose key names of the list. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In cases where you want to verify that a value is assignable to a type without *widening* it to that type and possibly throwing away information you care about, you can use a helper identity function, like this:

```
const itemDict = <K extends PropertyKey>(dict: { [P in K]: ItemType }) => dict;
```

Here `itemDict()` should only accept as an argument an object of the type you're looking for: whose keys are anything key-like `K extends PropertyKey` which will be inferred by the compiler when you call it, and whose properties are `ItemType`s.  Because the set of keys, `K`, is part of the type, it will not be forgotten:

```
const list = itemDict({
  first: { a: 1, b: 'one' },
  second: { a: 2, b: 'two' },
  third: { a: 3, b: 'three' },
});

list.second.a.toFixed(); // okay

list.fourth; // error!
// Property 'fourth' does not exist on type 
// '{ first: ItemType; second: ItemType; third: ItemType; }'
```

Notice that `list` is inferred by the compiler to be type `{first: ItemType, second: ItemType, third: ItemType}`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEloFsAqBPABzQG9hVUEAuVMAVywCNYBuM1B6gZwhnAHNWAX2DAkAezDdUIbABEQSCKgC8qADwBpVFAAe0MABNOqAAowxRGBDwaoeAHwAKAwojViqANonpYVBoBdakwoXEI0QQBKFXtUF0VWUQkpABsQKVUZUPlFR1JyOBAYbncKagBGABp2agByCSha1EFKtk4ocUNSqlQAJmqOVFqIAHcxJpa2CAALIoNu6gBmAbqZmChG5tao1jTuADp2zoN9hH2IMQAxEB0oA0dI5lQAemfUMQBrBDxgPYh9uBiWhWaZPV7aGDmGAAQmA4LMFlg1iGgOBMyaBjEUGMYDESl06SUElQ1iIqDhb1qHkKxTcGGw+CITyOEnm9NCjKgTxmc2CDPCT0EtX2jl6i0WAE5IkA)

Comment: I wanted this for writing a library for react-static-router with TypeScript, 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-static-routing